# using the mock folder for karma test in yeoman angularjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I have a angularjs application, which I generated with yeoman. In the karma.conf.js is a reference to test/mock/**/*.js. I have troubles to find out, how I use this folder. Currently I have a simple Service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('tvcalApp')
  .factory('Series', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/search/:search');
  });
```

and a Test

```
'use strict';

var $httpBackend;

describe('Service: Series', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('tvcalApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var Series;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_Series_) {
    Series = _Series_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
      var url_get = '/search/The%20Simpsons';

      var response_get = [{"seriesid": "71663"}];

      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

      $httpBackend.whenGET(url_get).respond(response_get);

  }));

  it('should return a list if search for The Simpsons', function () {
      var res = Series.query({search: 'The Simpsons'});
      $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(res[0].seriesid === 71663);
      });

});
```

This is working. But I wonder If I could use the mock folder from the karma.conf.js for the mocking function. Is it possible to move the mock part into the mock folder and use it for all unit test?

I could not find any example or documentation for this folder. Can someone please point me to to an example or documentation how to use the mock folder.

Comment: Have you managed to get any info on that?

Answer (score 7):

Basically i have done something like this looking at angular-mocks.js:
Let's say may app is called ql. and i have a loginService that i want to mock:

mocks/servicesMock.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var ql = {};
ql.mock = {};

ql.mock.$loginServiceMockProvider = function() {
  this.$get = function() {
    var $service = {
      login: function() { }
    };
    return $service;
  };
};

angular.module('qlMock', ['ng']).provider({
  $loginServiceMock: ql.mock.$loginServiceMockProvider
});
```

Then in my tests i can injeck $loginServiceMock:

```
'use strict';

describe('LoginController tests', function () {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('ql'));
  // load our mocks module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('qlMock'));

  var loginController,
    loginServiceMock,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  // $loginSericeMock will be injected from serviceMocks.js file
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $loginServiceMock) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    loginServiceMock =  $loginServiceMock;
    loginController = $controller('LoginController', {
      $scope: scope,
      loginService: loginServiceMock
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The example by @gerasalus is useful, but to answer the question:

`mocks` is just a folder to put your code in to keep your project organized and the code in tests short and to the point.  By keeping all your mocks in one place, it is easier to reuse them in tests... copying them from one test to another would be bad practice from a DRY perspective.

So, for example, you might have a service called 'Foo'

```
app/service/foo.js
```

Then you might create a mock of that service, called 'FooMock'

```
test/mocks/service/foo.js
```

And then you would create tests and inject whatever mocks you need, as is shown in gerasulus's answer.